# Como copiar um banco do SQLiteStudio para o eclipse?

Tags: android

Tenho um tabela criada do **SQLiteStudio** que ao ser copiada para a pasta `assets` em um aplicativo **Eclipse** não funciona.

No caso a minha classe de banco terá apenas um método listar( que é o que eu preciso) pois o banco já esta criado com a tabela e os dados.

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {

     private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "rtw";  




        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {  
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
        }  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }


      public List<String> getAllLabels(){  
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  

            // Select All Query  
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM regiao where uf = 'RS' " ; 

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();  
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);//selectQuery,selectedArguments  

            // looping through all rows and adding to list  
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
                do {  
                    list.add(cursor.getString(1));//adding 2nd column data  
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());  
            }  
            // closing connection  
            cursor.close();  
            db.close();  

            // returning lables  
            return list;  
        }
```

Como solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei usando uma classe que faz a copia do banco na hora que o aplicativo é rodado, basta deixar o arquivo de banco no diretório **assets**, que ao chamar a classe ele pega o arquivo e copia para o dispotivo, vejam:

```
 */
public class BdCopy {


 public static void copiaBanco(Context ctx, String nomeDB){

   // Cria o banco vazio
   SQLiteDatabase db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(
     nomeDB, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

   db.close();

   try {
     // Abre o arquivo que deve estar na pasta assets
     InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(nomeDB);
     // Abre o arquivo do banco vazio ele fica em:
     // /data/data/nome.do.pacote.da.app/databases
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
       ctx.getDatabasePath(nomeDB));

     // Copia byte a byte o arquivo do assets para
     // o aparelho/emulador

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int read;
     while ((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
       fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
     }
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você tem que copiar para a pasta assets e depois mover para o diretório `/data/data/SEUPACOTE/databases`.

Aqui tem um link que vai te ajudar, ***embora esteja em inglês***, é fácil de entender.

[Usando sua base de dados SQLite em apps Android](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)
**Edit:**

Há também uma lib que facilita o processo pra você aqui:

[Android SQLITE Asset Helper via GitHub](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

Comment: Tentei pelo emulador, No meu diretorio data/data/package  não aparece database, eu tenho que criar esses database? mas eu ja tenho criado quero apenas copiar

Comment: O que ele faz é basicamente isso:

Verifica se o db no diretório /data/data/SEUPACOTE/databases já existe.

Se não existe ele copia os bytes da pasta assets para onde deve.

São 2 classes, uma utilitária (com os métodos de copiar e verificar se existe, etc) e a outra é o exemplo do uso desta classe utilitária...